# mongodb I can't get city info by city id in the another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please, help..
I have two collections:

hotels:

```
    _id: ObjectId("5edabde015563b1ed0058862")
    address: Object
        city: ObjectId("5ee381b36da22c44405003cb")
        street: "Avenue de la Lanterne 50"
```

cities:

```
    _id: ObjectId("5ee381b36da22c44405003cb")
    label: Barselona
```

How can I get city label by id in hotel?

I'm doing like this, but not working:

```
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "cities",
        "localField": "address['city']",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "city"
    }
}
```

Mongoose schemes:

```
    const hotelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        address: {
            address: {
                city: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, trim: true },
                street: { type: String, trim: true },
            }
        }
    })

    const citySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        label: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you try `"localField": "address.city"`?

Comment: tried, not working (( I think, problem is in "_id", I don't no why

Comment: is `address.city` a string or an `ObjectId` ?

Comment: _id is ObjectId

Comment: in scheme:    city: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, trim: true },

Comment: it looks like a string in your pasted example though...

Comment: Right, it's an old error, i fixed it now, but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215837/discussion-between-kompaniietst-and-mickl).

Comment: Wow..! working now) Thanks, mickl!)))